# Typescript generic function to iterate over type keys

Tags: typescript

New to Typescript... is it possible to write a generic function in typescript which will print the keys of a given type? Something like:

```
const getKeys = <T>(): string[] => { ??? }

interface A {
  a: string,
  b: number
}

getKeys<A>(); // returns ["a", "b"]
```

**Rationale**: I want to write a function which will get a raw object and a type and will check if it contains all the keys from that type. I don't want to pass the keys for every type!

```
const checkKeys = <T>(rawData: any): boolean => { ??? }

interface A {
  a: string,
  b: number
}

const wrong = {
  x: "aaa",
  y: "bbb",
};

checkKeys<A>(wrong); // return false
```

I can write something like this:

```
const checkKeys = <T, K = keyof T>(data: any, ...keys: K[]) => {
  for (const key of keys) {
    if (!data[key]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

interface A {
  a: string,
  b: number,
}

const right = { a: "a", b: "b" };
const wrong = { c: "a", b: "b" };

checkKeys<A>(right, "a", "b")); // returns true
checkKeys<A>(wrong, "a", "b")); // returns false
```

**But I always have to pass the keys for every type I want to call it on, really annoying!**

I know that Typescript is just the type system and we need something at runtime, but is there a way that Typescript can generate the values for `keys` at compile time since it knows them in my case and even can check that I am passing only the acceptable values for `keys` parameter? If it is that smart during compile time, it could generate an array for me when compiling to Javascript. Is there a way that I'm not aware of?

Comment: No, there is not TypeScript-only way to do this.

Comment: Are you the one designing the types or is it someone else's code?

Comment: @JSmart523 I'm the one designing the types. I get JSON objects from client requests in my nodejs environment and have my own expected incoming parameter interfaces defined, so I need a utility function to effectively check that the raw json objects that I'm getting from the client apps are actually conforming to the interfaces that I defined and throw/response an error if not. And since I have dozens of endpoints and request interfaces, I would like to have a single utility function that will generically called in all of the handlers.

Comment: I've been told that we are expected to use libraries like https://zod.dev/ for this: i.e. define "type" definition (schema) as userland data structure, "infer" type from that, and offload the parsing + validation to the library. (Haven't tried yet, just skimmed docs.)
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/zod

Answer (score 2):

Typescript won't generate code for you.

The closest thing you could have is creating the possible keys in advance :

```
const keys = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const;
type Keys = typeof keys[number] // 'a' | 'b' | 'c'

type Foo = Record<Keys, string>; 

const foo: Foo = {
  a: 'foo',
  b: 'bar',
  c: 'baz',
}
```

Here `keys` is a array you can iterate over.

Comment: Probably not to useful for him since his `inferface` has both `string` and `number` props

Comment: @TobiasS. I'm with you on this, just wanted to be explicit !

Answer (score 0):

```js
const sample = {
  a: '123',
  b: 123
}

type Dict = { [key: string | number]: any}
type CheckKeys<T extends Dict, S extends Dict> = keyof T extends never ? false : (keyof S extends keyof T ? true : false)

function checkKeys<
  T extends Dict,
  S extends Dict,
>(data: T, smp: S): CheckKeys<T, S> {
    const smpKeys = Object.keys(smp)
    for (const key in data) {
        if (!(key in smpKeys)) return false as CheckKeys<T, S>
    }
    return true as CheckKeys<T, S>
}

const right = { a: "a", b: "b" };
const wrong = { c: "a", b: "b" };

// const checkRight: true
const checkRight = checkKeys(right, sample);

// const checkWrong: false
const checkWrong = checkKeys(wrong, sample);
```

Comment: First, it doesn't compile. Second, why is the check function tied to a single type? I need to pass a lot of different interfaces. Third, you check the keys of sample to be all present in the interface while I want the opposite. The only trick that I like here is creating a sample object for each interface I define just to be able to skip passing the keys, but I don't think I will be able to automate creation of a sample object for each arbitrary interface that I have.

Comment: Updated the answer to accepts different samples as function arguments. If you've multiple samples, you'll have to create them, but that's similar to your initial approach with interfaces. (The keys of) an interface, however, can't be used as reference during runtime.